# Views in other DB performance

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about views performance in SQL Server (2012+). Let's say I have 2 DBs on the same server and I create views in DB2 referencing tables in DB1, are there scenarios where the performance could be affected? I tested this with a locally installed DB and I could not see any performance issue, but I wonder if there's a risk of doing that in production. Any other concerns I should have doing that?

Comment: Performance depends upon the no of rows and columns in the table, If the view doesn't contain many joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I have 2 DBs on the same server and I create views in DB2 referencing tables in DB1, are there scenarios where the performance could be affected?

Queries and views that cross databases on the same SQL Server instance have no significant performance difference from queries and views within a single database.